# how read not empty lines of file in StreamReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-management

i want check if lines of file is more than 20 (for example) then prevent user to upload text file so want read file only once this is my code

```
    using (Stream stream = fileUploadBatch.FileContent)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string line = null;
            List<string> fileLines = new List<string>();
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream && fileLines.Count < 50)
            {
                line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                if(strig.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                    return;
                fileLines.Add(line);                          
             }

             // do something with list
        }
    }
```

this is bad practice because result of `streamReader.ReadLine()` assigns to line variable and create memory issues (string is immutable)
so i want add not empty line in to list without storing in line variable

Comment: Can you be more specific about those memory issues you're afraid of? It's a tiny stream, the whole block is wrapped into a using statement (and will be disposed ASAP), and it's not clear how an "immutable string" contributes to any memory.

Comment: A StreamReader reads; it does not filter. I am not aware of other reader mechanisms that do. And even if it would filter, it would first have to **allocate memory** for the new line before it can see if the line should be skipped or not. Also, I agree that this case is so insignificant that you shouldn't worry at all.

Comment: every time we assign some string into string variable in allocate new space in memory and pointer of string variable will refer to new space assume line number of uploaded file is more than 10000 then there is 10000 space in memory that used only for checking in null or empty i afraid if end users of my website use this page very much with this code

Comment: You could break out of the while loop once you have read more than 20 non-blank lines to avoid the time and memory it would take to read a very large file.  Also note that string is a reference type, so you are adding the reference to the string into the list, and not a copy of the string.

Comment: The only way to improve (a little) would be to throw from inside the read-loop. Now you read all 100000 lines, and then you throw if count > 20. Do that check inside the loop, this will make it abort a lot sooner (especially with little or no empty lines present).

Comment: thanks @juharr your answer looks nice because allocation of memory in maximum is lines of my config i will edit code with your answer

Comment: @SadeghAlinejad You should be able to just change the loop to `while (!streamReader.EndOfStream && fileLines.Count <= 20)`

Comment: thanks again @juharr it will less memory allocation :)